# How to create WADL document for spring based JAX WS service?

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-ws, wadl

I have created a **Spring Restful API** based Web service.
Please suggest how can I create a **WADL document** for this service.

I access the Web Service through eclipse by :

http://localhost:8080/SampleSpringService/mcxService/getMCX

**Service Name** : mcxService, 
**Function name** : getMCX

Java File code which is being called as Web Service:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/mcxService")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:FileProperty.properties") 
public class MCXController {


@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Value("${jsonFile.path}")
private String jsonFilePath;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getMCX", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")


public String getMCXData(HttpServletRequest request) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage("jsonFile.path", null, null));

    // read Form data to String

    String data = request.getParameter("firstname");
    System.out.println("data = " + data);
    if(data == null){return "Data is NULL !!!!" ;} 
    saveUserList(data);

    return "Data (" + data + ") is saved to File : D:/test.txt" ;

}
```

Comment: http://localhost:8080/SampleSpringService/mcxService/getMCX?wsdl

Comment: I am seeking WADL as someone told  that WSDL is not possible in spring based REST Web service. 
And after trying your option its just taking parameter value as **null**, running the service and providing result for the value of **null**.

Comment: are you sure it's JAX-WS? JAX-RS is more appropriate for REST programming. JAX-WS works with WSDL not WADL. Show some code.

Comment: I just added the Eclipse Web service project Structre Image. Hope it will help you.

 http://i.stack.imgur.com/uwZHe.png

Comment: no it doesn't. That folder is there for any Java EE application in eclipse

Comment: I am using Spring Restful API not separately JAX-WS. Just added the code for Java File **in question** which is being called as Web Service.